# Do you need to use article when using acronym

Tags: articles, acronyms

Do you need an article in a phrase "He moved to US five years ago"? Should it be "He moved to **the** US five years ago", since "US" is an acronym for something that should be always used with an article, like: "he moved to the United States five years ago".

Comment: How would you read it out?

Comment: I'm not sure what "rules" apply, but it should be "moved to the US".

Comment: You don't actually need to use it, but a well-mannered person would. Why not? It ain't that difficult. Three letters, two sounds: it doesn't take that much of an effort.

Comment: @Agzam https://books.google.fr/books?id=6hsXaubMCgcC&pg=PA257&dq=%22moved+to+united+states%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBGoVChMIw6aFmu7tyAIVjIYaCh2UBA6N#v=onepage&q=%22moved%20to%20united%20states%22&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you need an article in a phrase "He moved to US five years ago"? Should it be "He moved to the US five years ago", since "US" is an acronym for something that should be always used with an article, like: "He moved to the United States five years ago".

Yes and yes.